# Cannot correctly get expected Union output for SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, union, coderunner

**Troubles:**

Did not Order By properly and have not laid out code/or used conventions as expected.

**Question:**

The `Union` operator needs to be used here and to that end, find `vendor_id`'s specified in line three of the code used and a quantity of less than what is specified in the final line of code. The code will need to be sorted.

Code used:

```
SELECT job_id, po_id, 'Vendor ' || vendor_id as 'Reason'
FROM pos
WHERE vendor_id IS 'SOS'
UNION
SELECT job_id, po_id, 'Quantity < ' || quantity as 'Reason'
FROM pos
WHERE quantity < 10;
```

Meant to get:

```
job_id      po_id       Reason
----------  ----------  ------------
002         AAA         Quantiy < 10
004         CCC         Quantiy < 10
004         CCC         Vendor SOS
005         EEE         Vendor SOS
006         GGG         Quantiy < 10
```

Received (from CodeRunner):

```
Runtime error
Program does not use the expected ORDER BY clause or is badly laid out.
```

---

[See database schema for more details (Primary Keys are in bold).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u42T.png)

Unknown DBMS used. Behaves like `PostgreSQL` and not `mysql`.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: job_id 004 and 005 both have a vendor_id of SOS. job_id 002, 004, 006 have 2, 4, 2 as their quantity respectively. 

Quantity is spelled as Quantiy for some reason.

Comment: The error is a mystery because you have no `ORDER BY` in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by `job_id` follow by `po_id`, just add `ORDER BY` clause at the end of query. By default the sort order `ASC` (ascending), you may add `DESC` if you want to sort in descending order.

```
SELECT
    job_id, 
    po_id, 
    'Vendor ' || vendor_id as 'Reason'
FROM pos
WHERE vendor_id = 'SOS'

UNION

SELECT 
    job_id,
    po_id, 
    'Quantity < ' || quantity as 'Reason'
FROM pos
WHERE quantity < 10

ORDER BY 
    job_id,
    po_id;
```

Comment: Thank you Shuwn, everything is great, I just need to make it so the quantities do not appear, all I need the table to say is 'Quantity < 10' rather than saying 'Quantity < 2' when the quantity = 2 etc.

I have managed to fix this however, with minor tweaks.

Comment: It worked! I have placed another question to StackOverflow.

Comment: If my answer helps, why not mark it as answer then.

Comment: Apologies, I have just assigned this to your post. Thank you!